# In need of assistance with writing a Registration Handler Test Class

Tags: auth-provider, registration-handler

I am in need of assistance here. Trying to implement a Registration Handler test class for production deployment, I don't seem to get the test class working, nor do I really know how to write tests.
Not a developer here, so please forgive me if code seems odd or incorrect. I have been trying to put the code together from several places, after modifying the Salesforce's own automatically created handler. Many thanks in advance for any help.

Registration Handler:

```
global class RegAuthHandler implements Auth.RegistrationHandler {
    
    global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
        
        User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = :data.email];
        if (String.isBlank(data.email)) {
            return null;
        }

        return u;
    }
    
    global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
        
        User u = new User(id=userId);
        u.email=data.email;
        update(u);
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class RegAuthHandlerTest {
    static testMethod void testCreateAndUpdateUser() {
        
        RegAuthHandler handler = new RegAuthHandler ();
        Auth.UserData sampleData = new Auth.UserData('testId', 'testFirst', 'testLast',
                                                     'testFirst testLast', 'testuse8888r@example.org', null, 'testuserlong', 'en_US', 'facebook',
                                                     null, new Map<String, String>{'language' => 'en_US'});
        try{
            User u = handler.createUser(null, sampleData);
            System.assertEquals('testuserlong@salesforce.com', u.userName);
            System.assertEquals('testuser@example.org', u.email);
            System.assertEquals('testLast', u.lastName);
            System.assertEquals('testFirst', u.firstName);
            System.assertEquals('testuser', u.alias);
            insert(u);
            String uid = u.id;
            
            sampleData = new Auth.UserData('testNewId', 'testNewFirst', 'testNewLast',
                                           'testNewFirst testNewLast', 'testnewuser@example.org', null, 'testnewuserlong', 'en_US', 'facebook',
                                           null, new Map<String, String>{});
            handler.updateUser(uid, null, sampleData);
        }catch(Exception e){
            
        }
        // User updatedUser = [SELECT userName, email, firstName, lastName, alias FROM user WHERE id=:uid];
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to remove the try catch block in test and see if the test case is failing while running.

Comment: Thanks @manjit5190 for the advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't done so already, you should go through the [apex testing module on trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing). It's not going to tell you *exactly* how to write this test, but it introduces the general concepts (create test data, explicitly call the code you are trying to test, gather results and assert). Even if you don't describe yourself as a programmer, you'll need to know some programming basics to be able to progress here.

There are some issues/mistakes that I see in `RegAuthHandler` (like the `createUser` method not actually creating a user if one doesn't already exist), but let's focus on the unit test class.

#### The first thing I want to say

is that *you can have more than one test method*. In 99% of cases, I'd go so far as to say you *should* have more than one test method. Generally speaking, you only want to test a single scenario in any given test method. Instead of having one test method `testCreateAndUpdateUser`, I'd break that up into at least 2 tests (one to test `createUser`, another to test `updateUser`).

Having many, smaller test methods usually means that it's easier and faster to see all of what went wrong. If your tests are testing too much, you'll find yourself running the same test multiple times to figure out what each error is.

#### The primary issue with your test class: variable scoping and try/catch

In many programming languages (Apex included) variables have a *scope*, the area in code which they can be used. Variables declared inside of a block (i.e. between a matching set of `{` and `}`) can only be used inside of that block (and blocks nested within it).

```java
public void myMethod(){
    // This variable is declared inside of the block for "myMethod", and can only be used in
    //   this method
    Integer myInt = 0;

    if(someCondition == true){
        // This variable is declared inside another block
        // Again, it is only available inside this block
        Integer otherInt = 0;

        // You can use myInt here, because we're still in the code block for "myMethod"
        myInt += 1;
    }

    // Now that we're outside of the if()'s block, we can no longer use "otherInt"
    // "otherInt" is said to be "out of scope"
    // If this line is uncommented, it will cause an error
    // otherInt += 2;
}
```

That one of the main issues with your test. `User updatedUser = [SELECT userName, email, firstName, lastName, alias FROM user WHERE id=:uid];` is trying to use the `uid` variable, but that variable is out of scope (it's defined in the `try` block).

The other big issues are the empty `catch` block (which is bad practice, as it consumes any errors so that you can't see what the issue is), and having the try/catch blocks in your test in the first place.

try/catch is a way to handle exceptions, things that would normally cause your code to crash (like dividing by 0). It gives us a way to "pause" our code in a sense, and write a log or send off an email so that someone can investigate what went wrong.

Using try/catch in a unit test is harmful because if something is failing, you *want* to know about it. That's most of the point and usefulness of unit tests right there, notifying you when something is broken.

Provided that the test itself is correct, a failing test means that there's an issue you need to fix in the code being tested.

#### Moving forward from here

If you remove the try/catch (which you *really* should do) and start failing at your first assertion `System.assertEquals('testuserlong@salesforce.com', u.userName);`, that tells you a few things.

- You don't have a `User` record for the email you supplied through `Auth.UserData`
- If you didn't find a `User` record, your `createUser` method did not *create* a new user record (and then return that user record)
- Or, if you did find a `User`, the `User` that you found has a different username

In this case, I think it's safe to say that this test failure does indicate that you need to make a change to the class being tested, `RegAuthHandler`. It has some issues, and doesn't behave as you expect it to.

#### Some general advice

We generally need to create whatever data that our tests require ourselves (as part of the test method). `User` is special in that tests will *always* have access to existing `User` records, but it's still a good idea to create test data yourself.

I imagine the issue is that you don't have a `User` for `testuse8888r@example.org`, your `createUser()` method is returning null, and you're getting a `Null Pointer Exception` when trying to execute your first assertion.

SOQL queries (e.g. `[SELECT Id FROM Account]`) return a list of records. Assigning the result of a query to a single instance of an SObject is somewhat dangerous because it only works when there is *exactly* one record in the result. `List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id FROM Account];` is much safer (even if it is slightly more annoying to use).

If your query returns no records, the name of your method, `createUser`, suggests that you should create a new user. If you use a List to store the results, then `myList.isEmpty()` or `myList.size() == 0` is how you'll know that the query returned no records.

It's generally good practice to verify that method arguments (e.g. portalId, userId, data) are not null before you try to use them.

Comment: Thank you @Derek F for pointing me toward a correct thinking and solution. I managed to get it working, mostly by revising the test altogether.